# Why is there a side effect of using `breaklines=true` inside longtable on the adjacent cell?

Tags: vertical-alignment, listings, longtable

I noticed using `breaklines=true` option for `lstlisting` in one cell in a table, causes the text in the next cell in the same table row to shift down a little, even though the next cell does not use `lstlisting` at all.

Here is an example of two tables. First uses `breaklines=true` in one cell and the second table does not. Notice how the 3rd cell text in first table does not start at the top. There seem to be a new line added automatically there for some reason.

[image]

Here is the code. Compiled using `lualatex` with textlive 2021 updated about 3 weeks ago.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lstautogobble}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}   

First table. Using breaklines

\begin{longtable}[c]{|p{0.4in}|p{2in}|p{2in}|p{0.8in}|}\hline 
A& {\footnotesize \begin{dmath*}x^{2} \left(2 x^{2}+x +1\right) y^{\prime \prime}+x \left(7 x^{2}+6 x +3\right) y^{\prime}+\left(-3 x^{2}+6 x +1\right) y = 0\end{dmath*}}&
\begin{minipage}{2in}%
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\footnotesize,breaklines=true]
2nd order, with linear sym
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
&A\\\hline
\end{longtable}    

Second table. not using breaklines

\begin{longtable}[c]{|p{0.4in}|p{2in}|p{2in}|p{0.8in}|}\hline 
A& {\footnotesize \begin{dmath*}x^{2} \left(2 x^{2}+x +1\right) y^{\prime \prime}+x \left(7 x^{2}+6 x +3\right) y^{\prime}+\left(-3 x^{2}+6 x +1\right) y = 0\end{dmath*}}&
\begin{minipage}{2in}%
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\footnotesize]
2nd order, with linear sym
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
&A\\\hline
\end{longtable}    
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: why are you using minipage at all here, since you are using a `p` column anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not related to listings really, simply that you have used a `minipage` with its default `[c]` vertical alignment. So the baseline of the table row goes through the vertical centre of the minipage and the baseline of the A.  If you used `\begin{minipage}[t]` then the reference point would be on the top line and the baseline of A would align with that.

You would see the same with the more common markup of using an `m` column instead of a `p` column rather than a nested `minipage`